# What is break point in code debugging?

Tags: c

I recently started learn programming with c. As I'm new to programming scenario I don't have much knowledge. 
I would like to ask what does break point means in code block while code debugging? And how break point works?

Can you guys explain me how to debug with break point.

Thanks

Comment: it's a point where the program breaks, so you can use a debugger to inspect the internal state of the program. that's all.

Comment: Step 1: Go to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page). Step 2: type "breakpoint" into the search box. Step 3: press Enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breakpoint is a place in your code, where you want the execution to stop to allow you to examine the program data and/or state. It is used for debugging and set/removed by the debugger software. There are two types of breakpoints.

- Software breakpoint: the debugger is physically replacing the instruction at the specified address by a special `breakpoint` instruction (`bkpt` for ARM, `int 3` for x86 e.t.c). When the processor is encountering this instruction, it is stopping and waiting for the debugger.
- Hardware breakpoint - this one is available only in case the processor is supporting it, and usually only a limited number of these are available. This is a special hardware feature, so there is no need to replace the memory instructions, but just "tell" the processor (using JTAG or any othe debugging protocol) that we want it to stop at specific address.

Generally the hardware breakpoints are more robust and precise, as they are not modifying the program code and do not rely on the ability of the process to fetch and execute the breakpoint instruction.

Answer (score 2):

A break point is a mark in your code where the debugger should stop so you can check values of variables and the general state of program's execution.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program using a debuger the code stops before runing the line that is marked with a breakpoint and it allows you to ckeck the values of variables at that moment.